# AWS Cognito: Access request header detail in pre authentication Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, request-headers, pre-authentication

Is there any way to access request header origin [pre authentication trigger Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html)?

Comment: Simply curious, what are you trying to do? I ended up here searching for something similar. For me I was trying to pass custom error when business logic decides not to generate tokens.